# ElementTree appends extra information when getting root element

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an xml like shown below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <!DOCTYPE dtbook PUBLIC "-//INFO//INFO info 2005-3//EN" "http://url">
        <dtbook xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook/" version="2005-3" xml:lang="ml">
          <head>....
        </dtbook>
```

I open the file like so,

```
with open("filename.xml") as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()
```

When I try to get the root tag, I get,

```
print(root.tag)
{http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook/}dtbook
```

whereas if I remove all the attributes from the root tag i.e. dtbook, I get the correct output i.e. dtbook

```
print(root.tag)
dtbook
```

I cannot remove the attributes. Is there a way to get this working without removing the attributes??

Comment: What is it that you cannot get working? The output is correct. The name of the root element is `{http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook/}dtbook` and not just `dtbook`. Read about XML namespaces here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces.

Comment: Yo! I have taken down my previous comment as the link was sufficient to understand what the problem was!

Answer (score 1):

This is called a namespace and is supposed to be in front. You can simply remove the namespace by splitting your string at `{}`

Comment: Ok. I want to be able to use the root object to find the children. I am aware of the string manipulations.

Comment: Yo! Read the namespaces section and got what you meant. :)